# Toolbar doesn't touch sides of the screen

Tags: android, toolbar

I am trying to add Toolbar to my Activity but all I get is this:
[image]

Why isn't my toolbar touching edges of the screen? Here is my layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".EkranGlowny">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying a padding to the `RelativeLayout` which is creating the behaviour.

Remove

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

from your `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove this lines to touch the sides of the screen:

```
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

And then, remove this line to touch the status bar (orange line):

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

I suggest to delete this line too:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

And you can add margin for the last element, like this:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```